# オーバーレイの下にある要素でのキーイベントを無効化したい

Tags: javascript

オーバーレイ（画面を薄暗くする、擬似的なモーダルダイアログを作るときなどに使うやつ）を表示しているとき、オーバーレイよりも下にある要素へのマウス操作は無効化できますが、キーボード操作が無効化できません。
例えばTabキーでフォーカス移動して、Enterでボタンを押せたり。

あらかじめ画面上の操作可能な要素を洗い出して1つずつdisableしたり、keydownイベントハンドラの冒頭に条件分岐を書いたり、といった泥臭いやり方なら浮かびますが、もっとシンプルに実装できないものでしょうか。

オーバーレイ表示中は、操作可能な要素の方が少ないので、セレクタ指定などで「これら以外はキー入力を無視する」といった実装方法が取れるとだいぶ楽だと思っています。
例えば`active-on-overlay`というクラスのついた要素の子孫だけが操作可能だとして、

```
if ($(this).closest(".active-on-overlay").length !== 0) { ... }
```

とか・・・
jQueryの`on`を`document`に対して設定して全要素のイベントをうまく処理したりとか、何とかならないかと漠然とした考えもありますが、なかなか思いつきません。
すでに設定済みのイベントハンドラがあれば、それも止める必要もありますし・・・

ガチガチに完全に防ぐつもりは無く、誤操作の範囲を防止できればひとまず十分と考えていますが、何か良い方法は無いでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

通常、フォーカスがない限りはキーボードイベントは処理されないので、

- オーバーレイを表示したときにオーバーレイ外にフォーカスがないことを保証する
- オーバーレイを表示しているときにオーバーレイ外にフォーカスが移ったら、なんとかする

でうまくいくのではないかと思います。

下記コードサンプルで、`openDialog()`が1番目を、`focus`イベントリスナが2番目を処理しています。

`<dialog>`を使えば何も心配いらないのですけど、現状で使うのは厳しいですね。

```js
let showingDialog = false;
function openDialog() {
  document.querySelector('.backdrop').style.display = 'block';
  document.querySelector('.active-on-overlay').style.display = 'block';
  document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
  showingDialog = true;
  // ダイアログ内の要素にフォーカスを移しておく。
  document.querySelector('.active-on-overlay input').focus();
}
function closeDialog() {
  document.querySelector('.backdrop').style.display = 'none';
  document.querySelector('.active-on-overlay').style.display = 'none';
  document.body.style.overflow = 'auto';
  showingDialog = false;
}
document.addEventListener('focus', e => {
  // ダイアログ内でTABキーなどを押して外の要素にフォーカスが移ったら、
  // 強制的にダイアログ内にフォーカスを戻す。
  if (showingDialog && !e.target.closest('.active-on-overlay'))
    document.querySelector('.active-on-overlay input').focus();
}, true);
```

```css
.active-on-overlay {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  width: 30%;
  height: 20%;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
  z-index: 2;
  background-color: #eee;
  box-shadow: 4px 4px 4px gray;
}
.backdrop {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

```html
<input>
<dialog>
  <p>&lt;dialog>デス!</p>
  <input type=button value=Close onclick="document.querySelector('dialog').close();">
</dialog>
<input>
<br>
<button type=button onclick="document.querySelector('dialog').showModal();">
標準ダイアログを開く (2018年現在、Chromeのみ対応)</button>

<div class="backdrop"></div>
<div class="active-on-overlay">
  <p>自家製ダイアログです。</p>
  <input type=button value=Close onclick="closeDialog()">
</div>
<br>
<button type=button onclick="openDialog()">自家製ダイアログを開く</button>

<div style="height:9999px"></div>
```